# How to draw rectangle edge label in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation, labels, automata

I want to draw something like this. How to get that rectangle edge label?

[image]

This is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm,thick]

    \node[initial,state]        (A) []                          {};
    \node[state]         (B) [right of=A]                       {};

  \path[->] (A)  edge []    node []         {} (B);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How to get the Label?

Comment: I think you can do `\node[draw, shape = rectangle]`

Comment: Just use `\node [draw=black, text width=3.0cm] {Label};`  The `text width` is only if you want a larger box than the text as you have show. If this is being placed along an edge use `midway, above` option to place the node `midway` and `above` the line.

Comment: @dustin : Where should add that code?

Comment: @PeterGrill:  Where should put that code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On way would be to just add it to the `\path`:

```
\path[->] (A) edge [] node [draw=black, text width=3.0cm, midway, yshift=2ex]  {Label} (B);
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm,thick]

    \node[initial,state]        (A) []                          {};
    \node[state]         (B) [right of=A]                       {};

  \path[->] (A)  edge []    node [draw=black, text width=3.0cm, midway, yshift=2ex]         {Label} (B);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```